# How am I supposed to cast a char* into a Class type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to cast a char* into a Class of my own making and can't seem to get it to work without an error telling me that I simply can't cast a `char*` to type `Player`(my class name). The character pointer comes from a pointer array, `char *names[i], i = any index, names[i] = one of the names`, i.e. Austin or Kyle. With this I think `i` is a `char*`, but I could be wrong.

What I am trying to achieve over all is iterating through a vector of type `Player` and `push_back` each `char* i` to the vector while at the same time casting `i` to type Player. I sure hope this was specific enough I'll clarify if asked.

```
/*
Inside of my Blakjack constructor
*/
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
    //m_players is the vector of type Player
    //Player *p = new Player(names[i]);
    m_players.push_back(names[i]);
  }

/*
The Player.h File
*/
#include <vector>
class Player {
    public:
        Player(const char *name);

    private:
        int m_funds;
        char *m_name;
};

/*
The Player.cpp File
*/
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
Player::Player(const char *name){
    m_name = name; //I think this will work but it's hard to tell with my Blackjack
                     constructor still giving errors
    m_funds = 100;
}
```

Comment: This is not at all how C++ works. You can't change the type of something by casting it. Consult a good book on C++.

Comment: Are you trying to turn a string into an object name? While in Python you can use the `exec` statement to execute a string containing code, there's no such bridge between identifiers and strings in C++.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what casting means. Casting is changing type of object. Are you trying to create instances of `Player` of certain names from the `names` array but you have to make that your clear before I can help you.

Comment: Don't down my question I explained it the best I could without pictures. Once I have enough rep Ill make it more clear.

Comment: If everything you've told us is correct, then `m_players.push_back(names[i]);` should compile and run fine.  If not then you need to actually post your code instead of describing your code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a `Player` object for each name in an array of character strings.

If that's the case, you don't really want to cast a `char *` to a `Player`, you want to construct a `Player` for each `char *` in your array.  Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++)
{
    Player *p = new Player(names[i]);

    // Do something with p
    v.push_back(p); // ?? or something
}
```

This assumes your `Player` class has a constructor that looks like this:

```
Player::Player(const char *name)
```

and `v` is a `std::vector<Player>`

And if your Player class has this constructor, the language actually allows the char * to be implicitly converted into a Player (which may be what you're thinking of when you're trying to cast the char* into a Player):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++)
{
    v.push_back(names[i]); // adds a new Player, using the name stored in names[i]
}
```

**EDIT:** Your Player class also needs a default constructor:

```
class Player {

    public:
        Player(const char *name);
        Player() {};  // should probably initialize m_name and m_funds in here (set to 0 or something) just to be pedantic

    private:
        int m_funds;
        char *m_name;
};
```

This is needed in order to put your objects into a container such as std::vector.

Comment: I'm not certain this is a correct understanding of the problem.

Comment: I don't have enough rep for picture, but Jeff Loughlin has me intentions correct. However no matter what i do the compiler wont stop giving me the error "no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'. even though the function does match and my Player constructor looks just like Jeff's above.

Comment: I've also tried Jeff's code and it wont work for me, really wish I could post pictures. I have 3 pictures ready that would probably help out a lot.

Comment: Can you post some code? Show us the declaration for your Player class and the code for its constructor.

Comment: Just learned how to and posted it. If you need to see the whole beefy lot of code than I will but I think this should be good enough. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: Your Player class also needs a default constructor - Player::Player().  That constructor doesn't have to do anything, but it needs to be there.  C++ is weird that way...

Comment: @JeffLoughlin: That's not a C++ thing, `std::vector` requires it for certain members to work. (`push_back` is not one of them to my knowledge)

Comment: Ya it sure is weird. So I did that and the compiler was fine with it, but when I try something like 'cout << m_players[0] << endl;' to check to see what value was actually stored there I get an huge Error that usually implies that I'm trying to print garbage so instead I try 'cout << &m_players[0] << endl;'. This give no errors but instead prints a garbage hexadecimal so I'm guessing I'm trying to push something other than the player's names to the vector. However I know this isn't the case because the professor provided the entire main and method for storing names in the char* names[].

Comment: So, names[i] should be a name given with the command line argument in the Makefile that i also know has no problems.

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, I won't give you the answer, but here's a hint:  cout doesn't know how to print a Player object...

Answer (score 0):

Your Player constructor receives a const char* while your m_name member is char*. Assigning const char* to char* will not work.

Make your constructor Player::Player(char* name).

Comment: Better would be to make `m_name` be `char const *`.